# How to break ajax requests with mouse click

Tags: javascript, ajax

First ajax request is triggered after mouse click of Button A. Based on response received another ajax request is fired. This another request is fired in ajaxComplete event handler.
So my continuous ajax request chain works well.
Now I have a condition, if Button B is clicked, I need to break ajax chain.

Code worked in Chrome browser. In case of Firefox, Button B's onclick is not getting triggered. Also generic *$(document).on('click'..* event is not getting catched.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  async: false,
  type: post,
  dataType: dataType,
  data: data,
  success: xyz,
  error: abc
});

...

xyz = function() { binded = true }

...

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() { 
  if(binded || binded=='true') { 
    //fire ajax requests again and again till server gives timeout 
  }
});
$(document).on('click', 'input[id=openApplication]', function(event) { 
  binded = false;
  alert('Breaking ajax loop');
  // do form submit using Input - Sumbit type 
});
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried

Comment: Ajax request is fired using 
`$.ajax({
 url : url,
 async : false,
 type: post,
 dataType : dataType,
 data : data,
 success : xyz,
 error : abc
});`

in xyz method added one flag as 
`binded = true` 
on Form below code is written.
`$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
 if(binded || binded=='true') {
  //fire ajax requests again and again till server gives timeout
 }
});

$(document).on('click','input[id=openApplication]',function(event){
   binded = false;
   // do form submit using Input - Sumbit type 
});`

Comment: Please put everything in the post not in a comment